# on click Angular input box the checkbox above it is clicked in mozilla

Tags: angularjs

```
<label>
    <input class="radio" id={{ "phoneCheckBox"+$index}} type="checkbox" ng-model="phoneDetails.checked" ng-click="changeChecked($index)" />
    <div class="inputs" ng-class="{error: mobileMergeForm.extensionNumber.$dirty && mobileMergeForm.extensionNumber.$invalid}">
        <input type="tel" ng-model="phoneDetails.partialMobileNumber" readonly maxlength="8" ng-click="$event.stopPropagation();" />
        <input type="tel" name="extensionNumber" placeholder="" ng-pattern="/^\d{2}$/" ng-model="phoneDetails.extensionNumber" ng-disabled="isChecked($index)" class="lstdss" maxlength="2" ng-click="stopProp($event)" />
    </div>
</label>
```

on click of the second input box the ckecbox is clicked.  This happens only in mozilla.

Comment: Sorry the code was not being updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging got the answer.

need to use ng-click="$event.preventDefault()" at the input box.

i was using $event.satopPropagation() but that was not working.

I am still trying to find the exact reason fot this.

The code now is

```
<input type="tel" name="extensionNumber" placeholder="" ng-pattern="/^\d{2}$/" ng-model="phoneDetails.extensionNumber" ng-disabled="isChecked($index)" class="lstdss" maxlength="2" ng-click="$event.preventDefault()" />
```

If anyone can answer the reason for the issue, it would be nice.